# Large system of nonlinear equations

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, newton-raphson

I am trying to solve a problem, which I find quite hard, like, *headache-hard*. I have to solve the following set of $M$ nonlinear equations:
$$F(X)=\begin{bmatrix}f_1 (X)\\f_2 (X)\\...\\f_M (X)\\ \end{bmatrix}=0,X\in{}R^{N\times{}M}$$

With:

$$f_i\left(X\right)=x_{*,i}-F^{-1}\left[k\left(\omega{}\right)+\sum_{j=1}^Mq\left(\omega{}\right)\dot{}F\left[H^{\left(j\right)}\left(x_{*,j}\right)\right]\right]=0$$

Where $F$ is the Fourier transform and $H$ a nonlinear function, $k$ and $q$ are constants. $H$ has the following form:

$$H\left(x\right)=r{\left(\frac{x}{s}\right)}^{\alpha{}},\
s,\ r,\ x\in{}R$$

The highest $\alpha$ is, the harder it is to find a solution. I tried both simulated annealing and Jacobian-Free Newton Krylov, without much success. I believe an issue here might be the way I state the problem.

Should **JFKN** or **SA** compute a perturbation/update on each matrix element separately? It does not sound reasonable to me, as *I am dealing with timeseries, each column of* $X$ *being a timeseries of length* $N$; I guess then perturbations should be flexible yet consistent from one element to the next. Ha! A bit of insight or advice would be very much appreciated here!

Thank you

Comment: What is $x_{*,i}$? $s\in\mathbb{R}^N$ but you divide by $s$? Are $q$ and $k$ constants (in the equation you wrote a dependence in $\omega$)?

Comment: $x_{*,i}$ is the column $i$ of matrix $X$. In the expression of $H$, $x$ is a scalar, sorry. We want to get $H(x)$ for each element of $x_{*,i}$. $q$ and $k$ are indeed frequency dependent, but constant from one iteration to the next.